# Dealing with durations defined by days, hours, minutes such as “1d 3h 2m” in Python

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7

I have to validate a string with diffrent format of duration:

```
1d 8h 30m
12h 30m
0h 59m
59m
10h 0m
10h
1d 0h 0m
1d 0h 59m
1d 10h 0m
1d
```

I am new in python and don't have any idea about `regex` in python.

### **EDIT**

There is a textbox in which user insert work duration like the JIRA Worklog. So When user insert any of above string these are valid string.
But if user insert any invalid string then i need to show error message of invalid string format.

```
1g -- invalid
1d 3g -- invalid
1d 3h 30j -- invalid
```

and soon

So i just wanted to validate input string.

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Validate or parse or something else entirely?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, What basically you are looking for?

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/pR9sB3/1) ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub if i have entered '12d 2g' is an invalid string.. and i have using you regex in pytho re like > _exp = "(\d+d)?\s*((?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])h)?\s*((?:[0-5]?\d)m)?"
>>> import re
>>> re.match(_exp, '10h 30m')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4d8a62d588>
>>> re.match(_exp, '10h 30g')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4d8a62d620>
>>>

Comment: What the heck is `2g`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub 2g is not a valid string there should be `h` in place of `g`..

Comment: Yes! you are right g is not a valid...@ThomasAyoub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
^(\d+d)?\s*((?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])h)?\s*((?:[0-5]?\d)m)?$
```

In python ([see it live](https://ideone.com/DQLuWn)):

```
import re

p = re.compile(ur'^(\d+d)?\s*((?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])h)?\s*((?:[0-5]?\d)m)?$', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

time = input("Please enter your value: ")
if re.match(p, time):
    print("\nGreat " + time + " is a valid entry.")
else:
    print("\nOups... " + time + " is NOT a valid entry.")
```